# How to force Netbeans to only use the -ggdb compile flag without it also automatically emitting the -g flag in Makefile-Debug.mk

Tags: c++, netbeans, makefile

I’m running Netbeans 7.4 on Mavericks.  In order to be able to use gdb, compilation with the -ggdb flag seems to be necessary.  However, even though I specify it through the Project’s Properties/Additional Options wizard, Netbeans also emits -g during compilation.  Unfortunately, it turns out that this behavior has an adverse effect when the debugging session commences.  Is there any way to force Netbeans not to also emit -g?

Output during compilation:

g++ -m64 -ggdb   -c -g -Werror -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/macport_GNU-MacOSX/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/macport_GNU-MacOSX/main.o main.cpp

mkdir -p dist/Debug/macport_GNU-MacOSX

g++ -m64 -ggdb    -o dist/Debug/macport_GNU-MacOSX/executable build/Debug/macport_GNU-MacOSX/main.o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alexander.Simon@oracle.com responded here [1] to set "Development Mode" to "No Flags", then specify -ggdb in the "Additional Options".

1 - https://netbeans.org/projects/cnd/lists/users/archive/2014-02/message/12